# How to add two columns of a dataframe as Decimals?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I am trying to add two columns together using the `Decimal` module in Python but can't seem to get the syntax right for this. I have 2 columns called `month1` and `month2` and do not want these to become `float`s at any point in the outcome as division and then rounding will later be required.

The `month1` and `month2` columns are already to several decimals as they are averages and I need to preserve this accuracy in the addition.

I can see guidance online for how to add numbers together using `Decimal` but not how to apply it to columns in a pandas dataframe. I've tried things like:

```py
df['MonthTotal'] = Decimal.decimal(df['Month1']) + Decimal.decimal(df['Month1'])
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

def convert_decimal(row):
    row["monthtotal"] = Decimal(row["month1"])+Decimal(row["month2"])
    return row

df = df.apply(convert_decimal, axis =1)
```

Comment: sorry Rishin I should have stated, the month1 and month2 columns are already to several decimal places as they are monthly averages that I am adding together

Answer (score 0):

`decimal.Decimal` is designed to accept single value, not `pandas.Series` of them. Assuming that your column is holding strings representing number values, you might use `.applymap` for using `decimal.Decimal` element-wise i.e.:

```
import decimal
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['0.1','0.1','0.1'],'y':['0.1','0.1','0.1'],'z':['0.1','0.1','0.1']})
df_decimal = df.applymap(decimal.Decimal)
df_decimal["total"] = df_decimal.x + df_decimal.y + df_decimal.z
print(df_decimal.total[0])
print(type(df_decimal.total[0]))
```

output

```
0.3
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```